Error Accessing Sparse Embedding in Milvus Hybrid Search
I am following the hybrid search tutorial using BGE-M3 embeddings from Milvus, but I encounter an issue with this line of code: sparse_results = sparse_search(col, query_embeddings['sparse'][0]). It throws a NotImplementedError indicating that 1D sparse slices are not implemented.
I am using the following versions: milvus-lite==2.4.9, milvus-model==0.2.3, python=3.10.14. What could be causing this issue?

What OS are you running?   Which CPU?  Any GPU?   How much RAM?   Do you have adequate disk space?
Following https://milvus.io/docs/embed-with-bgm-m3.md
This works for me on Mac M1 architecture with Python 3.10
Embeddings: {'dense': [array([-0.02505938, -0.00142195,  0.04015466, ..., -0.02094925,
        0.02623658,  0.00324097], dtype=float32), array([ 0.0011846 ,  0.00649291, -0.00735767, ..., -0.01446293,
        0.04243685, -0.0179482 ], dtype=float32), array([ 0.0041529 , -0.01014917,  0.00098105, ..., -0.02559665,
        0.08084688,  0.00141646], dtype=float32)], 'sparse': <3x250002 sparse array of type '<class 'numpy.float32'>'
    with 43 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>}
Dense document dim: 1024 (1024,)
Sparse document dim: 250002 (1, 250002)

